# How to dissappear top layout when scrolling down the recycleview

Tags: android, css, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have developed for android apps using RecycleView.
I'm wondering, how can I "attach" a whole layout to my RecyclerView so that when I scroll down the layout scrolls out of sight along with it. Presently the Layout above the RecyclerView is fixed on the screen, whereas all the data in my RecyclerView is scrollable. I want the Layout to move out of sight as the user scrolls down the page as well. If you look at Instagram, all the user profile information at the top of your gallery disappears as you scroll down the page. How can I do this? How can I scroll the whole layout and disabling the scroll of Recycleview?

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:id="@+id/fullName"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:gravity="top"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:id="@+id/bio"
                android:paddingRight="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                android:padding="@dimen/item_margin"
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:visibility="visible"/>
```

Comment: What you're describing can be achieved very easily with the use of the new `coordinatorLayout`. Examples can be found all over internet, here is a pretty good one though : http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator

Answer (score 0):

i think you need something like `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, you can simply implement it in your project.

take a look at this [guide](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout)
 for more info :)

Comment: sorry but I should use the Recyclerview and please tell me more exactly.
could you write examples in details here?

Comment: you should use RecyclerView and CollapsingToolbarLayout together... did you see the guide link that i inserted in my answer?